# Queries permission level in Azure using KQL

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, kql

I was wondering how I can query the level of permissions in Azure AD via log analytics with KQL.
for example, I would like to have a query that outputs all the admins in my Tenant with global admin permission and Owner permissions in the subscription level. 
the final result that I want to achieve is creating an alert whenever admin is logged in to Azure.

Thanks for the help

Comment: If you would like to have help with the query, please provide sample of the data using inline datatable() operator.

Comment: I don't have such a sample. hoping that someone here can assist me.